# Getting the wrapper object in java

Tags: java, object, word-wrap

I am instantiating a `LinkTableColumn` object.
When instantiating - I am overriding the method, which needs my instance of `LinkTableColumn`.

When writing the following - compiler returns: "No enclosing instance of the type LinkTableColumn is accessable"

```
        LinkTableColumn linkTableColumn = new LinkTableColumn(){
            @Override
            public methodIAmOverridng() {
                return new ObjectNeedsLinkTableColumn(LinkTableColumn.this);
            }
        };
```

There is a workaround, which I would like to avoid. Is it possible somehow to write it down more clean?

```
        LinkTableColumn linkTableColumn = new LinkTableColumn(){
            final LinkTableColumn l = this;
            @Override
            public methodIAmOverridng() {
                return new ObjectNeedsLinkTableColumn(l);
            }
        };
```

Comment: You can directly use `this` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `this`

```
LinkTableColumn linkTableColumn = new LinkTableColumn(){
    @Override
    public methodIAmOverridng() {
        return new ObjectNeedsLinkTableColumn(this);
    }
};
```